# Add Multiple Items Such as an Array to Existing Kendo UI DataSource

Tags: kendo-ui, datajs

I've been working on this for a few hours and cannot manage to find a way to get it to work properly. I'm looking for the proper way to add the contents of an array to an existing Kendo UI DataSource. Basically I have 4 SharePoint lists and I am fetching data using DataJS from each list. I want to then display the items in a Kendo GridView but I don't want to add the items using a `for` statement and the `add()` method. I have tried using the `add()` method on the array directly but all this does is add the array as an object itself to the DataSource and, of course, that is not the intended behavior. I also attempted using `dataSource.data.concat()` but received the error:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'concat'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lets say that you have the new data in an array called `newData`. You can use:

```
var newData = [
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... }
];

$.merge(newData, datasource._pristine);
datasource.data(newData);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me because my datasource is a lazy-loading Web API service. So when I do this, the datasource isn't loaded yet and I get just the new constant items I was trying to merge. Am I stuck or is there a way to make this work with a Web API service?

Comment: Be careful of the order of your `$.merge()` arguments! if the `newData `should be **ap**pended (not **pre**pended), then it should be the **second** argument. Also in my kendo version the property `_pristineData`, not `_pristine`. Finally, by setting the `datasource.data(...)` to the new values directly with .data() you will "detach" the remote service. Instead I used the `schema: { data : function(){ } }` to return data as if it came back from the remote service already `merged`

Answer (score 1):

The above solution did not work for me. Suggested by a Telerik admin is the method below:

```
var vm = kendo.observable({
  data: new kendo.data.ObservableArray([])
});

vm.data.push.apply(vm.data, [ 1, 2, 3]);
```

This way results in one render for bound widgets. Found here: http://www.telerik.com/forums/passing-array-to-observablearray-push